# Arriving to home country after visa expires?

Tags: visas, transit, schengen-visas

I have a schengen visa valid till 21st Aug'16. My return ticket from Germany are booked for 21st Aug'16. But i shall be reaching India on the 22nd Aug'16 early morning - 3 am. Will this be causing any issue at the Indian airport ?

Comment: You are an Indian national? Your flight departs on the 21st before midnight? If both answers are yes, then there should be no issue, why?

Comment: As long as you passed customs etc before midnight you will be fine.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337: He doesn't need to pass customs before midnight -- just be sure to be out of the Schengen area before the visa runs out. Customs on arrival to India will not be interested in the visa for the place he _has been_. (This follows because customs never cares about visas anywhere. But neither will Indian _immigration_ care about visas for other countries).

Comment: @HenningMakholm I meant the Schengen customs area sorry for being unclear.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337: Schengen is not a customs area. Most Schengen countries are in the EU customs area, but there are EU countries that are not in Schengen (but still part of the customs union), as well as Schengen countries that are not in the EU and so have their own customs rules. In any case, there's usually no customs check when _leaving_ a country.

Comment: Yes. I am an Indian national. 
My flight departs from Germany in the morning of 21st Aug'16 and reaches India on early morning of 22nd Aug'16.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 What Henning Makholm is trying to say is that instead of *customs,* you should have said *immigration* or, more precisely, *the Schengen exit control.*

Answer (score 5):

As an Indian national, you can arrive in India anytime during your life.

It doesn't matter where you came from and what visa you might have needed there or not; the Indian government might not even know, but for sure they don't care.

Comment: As I understand it, your passport must still be valid, though...